# How to prevent "Blocked a frame" error when use google pay?

Tags: cross-domain, google-pay

I have configured Google Pay for sites and it works fine in Google Chrome. But when I am trying to use it in any different browser then I have a problem: on pay button click google opens pay.google.com window then I press pay and preloader never stops (onPaymentAuthorized callback is never called).

I tried google example https://jsfiddle.net/34wxopb2/ and it works fine. The only difference on my site which I found is error "Unhandled Promise Rejection: SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin..." which happens on google pay button click. So I guess this is the problem, because my code is identical to the jsfiddle example above. How to solve it?

```
<script async
  src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
  onload="onGooglePayLoaded()"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem was not in google pay as I expected. I passed paymentsClient instance to Vue data which changed its structure (made it a Proxy) and this caused the problem.